# Laravel 5 Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\riderect() Error

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, uploading

I’m new to the laravel and I’m developing a file uploading system. The files are uploaded and stored to the database just fine, but when I try to call the delete method, it gives this error:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\riderect()

Here is the FileUpload Controller and its delete method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\UploadedFile;

class FilesController extends Controller
{
public function deleteFile($id)
    {
        $file = UploadedFile::find($id);
        Storage::delete(config('app.fileDestinationPath').'/'.$file->filename);
        return riderect()->to('uploaded');
    }
}
```

How can this error be avoided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a spelling error, this:

```
return riderect()->to('uploaded');
```

Should be:

```
return redirect()->to('uploaded');
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `riderect()->to('uploaded');` with `redirect()->to('uploaded');`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.